# Hibernate exception. QuerySyntaxException: unexpected token: HAVING

Tags: java, hibernate, hql

I try use this HQL query:

```
   Result.find("SELECT c, ( 3959 * acos( cos( radians(?) ) * "+
    "cos( radians( c.latitude ) ) *"+
    "cos( radians( c.longitude ) - radians(?) ) +"+
    "sin( radians(?) ) * sin( radians( c.latitude ) ) ) ) " +
    "AS distance FROM City c HAVING distance < ? ORDER BY distance ASC",
    latitude, longitude, latitude, radius).fetch();
```

But in result:

```
IllegalArgumentException occured : org.hibernate.hql.ast.QuerySyntaxException: unexpected token: HAVING near line 1, column 204 [SELECT c, ( 3959 * acos( cos( radians(?) ) * cos( radians( c.latitude ) ) *cos( radians( c.longitude ) - radians(?) ) +sin( radians(?) ) * sin( radians( c.latitude ) ) ) ) AS distance FROM models.City c HAVING distance < ? ORDER BY distance ASC]
```

Answer (score 1):

try changing `HAVING` to `WHERE`, in your query.

Comment: Now `Unknown column 'distance' in 'where clause'`

Comment: `distance` is alias for the column, you have to put the whole calculation as in select, in where clause as well. instead of column alias

Comment: But then I can not sort the list of cities.

Comment: Hm... `Unknown column 'col_0_0_' in 'order clause'`

Comment: This query work: `SELECT c, ( … ) AS distance FROM City c ORDER BY distance ASC`. But without `WHERE`

Answer (score 1):

The keyword HAVING is only allowed if you use GROUP BY (think of having like WHERE for GROUPS).
See the [reference manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/select.html) for SELECT syntax.

Comment: Yes, you're right. Now I've corrected the 'having' to 'where'. And got an error: `Unknown column 'distance' in 'where clause'`

Comment: @AntonTsivarev You need to place the expression in a subquery to refer to distance.

Comment: @stacker, you cannot use a subquery expression in the from : "Note that HQL subqueries can occur only in the select or where clauses." http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/4.3/manual/en-US/html_single/#queryhql-subqueries

Answer (score 1):

The only way is to use a native query because :

- subselect is not possible : "Note that HQL subqueries can occur only in the select or where clauses." http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/4.3/manual/en-US/html_single/#queryhql-subqueries
- having is not possible without a group by
- where is not possible neither

Java code :

```
@Query(value = "SELECT s.*,\n" +
            "  (\n" +
            "    3959 * acos(\n" +
            "        cos(radians(s.lat))\n" +
            "        * cos(radians(:lat))\n" +
            "        * cos(radians(:lon) - radians(s.lon))\n" +
            "        + sin(radians(s.lat))\n" +
            "          * sin(radians(:lat))\n" +
            "    )\n" +
            "  ) AS distance\n" +
            "FROM Stop s\n" +
            "HAVING distance < 30\n" +
            "ORDER BY distance asc", nativeQuery = true)
    List<Stop> findClosestStops(@Param("lat") Double lat, @Param("lon") Double lon);
```

An alternative is to return a list of object containg the city + distance, but no where is possible, but you can limit the resultset

Comment: Worked for me. I was missing nativeQuery=true param in my code.
Just for those who are trying to execute the query in JPA then put, nativeQuery = true and try.

Answer (score 0):

Hm, what should be "?" parameter?

If true you should use it like

```
HAVING distance < :distance
```

and use

```
query.setParameter("distance", 50);
```

Answer (score 0):

try

```
 select dis.c,dis.distance(
    SELECT c,
     ( 3959 * acos( cos( radians(?) ) *  cos( radians( c.latitude ) ) * 
cos( radians( c.longitude ) - radians(?) ) + sin( radians(?) ) *
 sin( radians( c.latitude ) ) ) )  AS distance FROM City c  ) dis 
where dis.distance<? order by dis.distance ASC
```