# Spring Boot JPA - Finding locations which are within a given location range (lat,lng) and a radius (distance)

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I am trying to write a mysql query in Spring JPA to find locations within a given range. (I am using Spring Boot + Kotlin)

I am trying the following query:

```
@Repository
interface LocationRepository : JpaRepository<LocationEntity, Long> {

    @Query("SELECT id, (6371 * acos ( cos ( radians(:lat) ) * cos( radians( lat ) ) * cos( radians( lng ) - radians(:lng) ) + sin ( radians(:lat) ) * sin( radians( lat ) ))) AS distance FROM location GROUP BY address HAVING distance < :distance ORDER BY distance ASC", nativeQuery=true)
    fun filterByLocation(
        @Param("lat") lat: String,
        @Param("lng") lng: String,
        @Param("distance") distance: Int
    ): List<LocationEntity>
}
```

But I get the following error:

```
java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: Expression #1 of SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated column 'my_app.location.id' which is not functionally dependent on columns in GROUP BY clause; this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by
```

My location entity is the following:

```
@Entity(name = "location")
data class LocationEntity(
    var lat: Double,
    var lng: Double
) {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    val id: Long = 0
}
```

Comment: how can you use Having without group by clause?

Comment: @dassum it's working now. I had to add the "GROUP BY" before the "HAVING" keyword. Thanks!!

Comment: @dassum actually I just realised but it gives me now: "Unknown column 'distance' in where clause". My query is the following:

SELECT id, (6371 * acos ( cos ( radians(48.1369945) ) * cos( radians( lat ) ) * cos( radians( lng ) - radians(11.5689834) ) + sin ( radians(48.1369945) ) * sin( radians( lat ) ))) AS distance FROM location GROUP BY id  HAVING distance < 5 ORDER BY distance".

It seems my problem is not a new one. See here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10118449/hibernate-exception-querysyntaxexception-unexpected-token-having

Comment: please update your question with the revised query.

Comment: @dassum I changed my question...now it seems a new error is displayed.

Comment: you cannot use a non-aggregatable column along with group by. id column in the select clause is not using any aggregation.

Comment: You have used Distance in Having. As per my knowledge you can not do that and to make it work you can replace `distance < :distance` here replace the `distance` in the left hand side with the distance query again, i.e. `(6371 * acos...)`